# How can I query specific child in multiple-level relationship table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the multiple-level one-to-many tables, linked by the foreign key.

**I frequently query the specific child according to family_id, grandparents, and parent's name.**

The query result should be only one.

If a child does not exist, I'll create a new child record and link it to the given parent.

1. The number of the child table is much larger than the parent table.

   *Childs >>>> Parents >> Grandparents > families*
2. People from different families can have the same name.

   (The name in the child table can be the same because they might come from different families and different parents)

Here are the model definitions

```
class Families:
    __tablename__ = 'families'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    family_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    grand_parents = relationship(GrandParents, backref="family")

class GrandParents:
    __tablename__ = 'grand_parents'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    family_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("families.id"))
    parents = relationship(Parents, backref="grand_parent")

class Parents:
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    grand_parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("grand_parents.id"))
    childs = relationship(Childs, backref="parent")

class Childs:
    __tablename__ = 'childs'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id"))
```

For now, I use join to query the targeted child row by given family_id, grandparent's name, and parent's name

```
def get_child(family_id, grand_praent_name, parent_name, child_name):
    child = session.query(Childs)\
        .join(Parents)\
        .join(GrandParents)\
        .filter(GrandParents.family_id == family_id,
                GrandParents.name == grand_praent_name,
                Parents.name == parent_name,
                Childs.name == child_name).one_or_none()

    return child
```

But each time, I have to do this kind of query (go through all children for a specific family and update their value depending on business logic).

**Is there a better approach/design/idiomatic to do this kind of query?**

Comment: But what is the purpose of this query? You only need a child, or information from parent and gradparent also?

Comment: it's like an XML structure.  I want to update values in the child node, so I have to locate the child in specific parents and grandparents node. 
Each individual XML file is being recognized as a family and has an id.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good, if you only update `child`. You may consider using [`with_entities`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities) to avoid fetching to many unnecessary data:

```py
def get_child(family_id, grand_praent_name, parent_name, child_name):
    child = session.query(Childs)\
        .join(Parents)\
        .join(GrandParents)\
        .filter(GrandParents.family_id == family_id,
                GrandParents.name == grand_praent_name,
                Parents.name == parent_name,
                Childs.name == child_name)\
        .with_entities(Childs).one_or_none()

    return child
```

If you would like to update also `parent`  or `grandparent` you should use [`joinedload`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload) to avoid additional implicit queries.

If you encountered performance issues for your query you should add indexes to foreign keys to improve joining, e.g.:

```py
parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id"), index=True)
```